# Is it possible to get the Linux source code for mmap and the Windows source code for MapViewOfFile?

Tags: c++, windows, linux-kernel

Goog afternoon, I recently downloaded the www.kernel.org mainline 2.6.39 Linux kernel source distribution. We are looking for the Linux source code for void *mmap(void* start , size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset). After we decompressed the tar.bz2 distribution, we found a file mmap.c which contains memory mapping source code.
   However, we  could not the  Linux source code for void *mmap(void* start , size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset) in mmap.c.
   Do any Linux engineers or adminstrators knwo where we obtain the  Linux source code for void *mmap(void* start , size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset)?
   Also, we are interested in the Windows source code for MapViewOfFile. I know this a stretch because Microsoft OS source code is not in the open source domain.
   In case anybody is wondering why we need this source code, we are trying to optimize the runtime performant of a C++ deduplicating program prototype using a cached memory mapped file implementation on a 32-bit architecture. We want to understand how to use mmap and MapViewOfFile in order the optimize the runtime performant of our prototype? Thank you.

Comment: For Windows I'd probably look at the Wine source code.

Comment: @David: Nah, it'll just call `mmap`.  ReactOS on the other hand...

Comment: @David Heffernan. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `MapViewOfFile`, I'd check [Winbase.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it might just be the declarations, else you'd have to turn to reverse engineering, which is considered illegal in most countries.

I have found an extensive article [here](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch13.html) on MMAP and how it works. Maybe that helps.

Comment: I didn't downvote your comment. We would be happy if we find out about more about Linux void *mmap(void start , size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset)? We are planning to prototype on Linux first. Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

Pulling from android source code;

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

extern void*  __mmap2(void*, size_t, int, int, int, size_t);

#define  MMAP2_SHIFT  12
void*   mmap( void*  addr,  size_t  size, int  prot, int  flags, int  fd,  long  offset )
{
    if ( offset & ((1UL << MMAP2_SHIFT)-1) ) {
    errno = EINVAL;
    return MAP_FAILED;
  }

    return __mmap2(addr, size, prot, flags, fd, (size_t)offset >> MMAP2_SHIFT);
}
```

Source: [mmap.c](https://www.assembla.com/code/android-gb-for-sharp-is01/git/nodes/bionic/libc/unistd/mmap.c?rev=4a957aeda529dbe99770180b5c7bcd9363bde39d)

Now, the actual `__mmap2` call has assembly, so it's going to depend on your arch. Here's an x86 version:

```
/* autogenerated by gensyscalls.py */
#include <sys/linux-syscalls.h>

    .text
    .type __mmap2, @function
    .globl __mmap2
    .align 4

__mmap2:
    pushl   %ebx
    pushl   %ecx
    pushl   %edx
    pushl   %esi
    pushl   %edi
    pushl   %ebp
    mov     28(%esp), %ebx
    mov     32(%esp), %ecx
    mov     36(%esp), %edx
    mov     40(%esp), %esi
    mov     44(%esp), %edi
    mov     48(%esp), %ebp
    movl    $__NR_mmap2, %eax
    int     $0x80
    cmpl    $-129, %eax
    jb      1f
    negl    %eax
    pushl   %eax
    call    __set_errno
    addl    $4, %esp
    orl     $-1, %eax
1:
    popl    %ebp
    popl    %edi
    popl    %esi
    popl    %edx
    popl    %ecx
    popl    %ebx
    ret
```

Source: [__mmap2.S](https://www.assembla.com/code/android-gb-for-sharp-is01/git/nodes/bionic/libc/arch-x86/syscalls/__mmap2.S?rev=4a957aeda529dbe99770180b5c7bcd9363bde39d)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does that mean mmap2 is implemneted in assembly language only for Android? Does that is it is impossible to get Linux C code for void *mmap(void start , size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset)? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank The linux version will be part of the libc library being used. Most distributions use glibc. So you'll need to check the source of that. http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.9.tar.gz Has the latest release version as of writing. The file you are looking for is `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/mmap.S` (for x86). Yes, the actual code is done in ASM. This was meant to show a more simplified version.

Comment: #onteria_, Thank you for your answer. I will start accepting answers this evening. I just downloaded . ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.9.tar.gz and found mmap.S. Do you know how mmap.S related to linux kernel source code in mmap.c? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

To get the Win32 `MapViewOfFile` implementation, you will have to pay an expensive subscription, sign legal nondisclosure agreements, etc.

linux `mmap` is publicly readable.  However, you should know that there are two parts: The `mmap` function in glibc, and the matching syscall in the kernel, where all the interesting bits are.  The signature you showed is for the glibc function, don't expect the syscall to have the exact same parameters.

But you can "understand how to use `mmap` and `MapViewOfFile`" without reading the implementation.

Comment: @Ben Voight, Thank you for your answer. Wg just downloaded a glibc distribution, ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.9.tar.gz, We can't find the mmap function in *.h header files or the *.c source files. Do you know where we can find the linux mmap function in the glibc distribution? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: it's an auto-generated wrapper that does nothing except package up the parameters and make a syscall.  `mmap.c` in the kernel is where all the work is done.  I only mentioned the glibc layer because it changes the parameters.

Comment: @Ben Voight, Thank you for your answer. Do you know where we can find the auto-generated wrapper that packages the parameters and make a syscall to the kernel mmap.c. Thank you for your help. I'll start accepting answers this weekend.

Comment: @Frank: From looking at the makefile, it's in `sysdeps / unix / sysv / linux / syscall-list.h`.  This file is generated by the glibc build process, it won't exist in the download.

Comment: @Ben Voight, Thank you for your answer. I will try to build glibc library tonight,

Comment: @Ben Voight, I am trying to build the glibc right now. When I go to the directory /home/frank/DQT/glibc-2.9, where I decompressesd the glibc-2.9.tar.gz file, I run the ./configure script. I then get the message : configure error you must configure in a separate build directory. Then I go to /home/frank/DQTTest5 and run /home/frank/DQT/glibc-2.9/configure. The configure script then runs to completion . But then when we run make home/frank/DQT/glibc-2.9/Makefile, we get back the message Nothing to be done for  home/frank/DQT/glibc-2.9/Makefile. What should we do now? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Just `make`, not `make Makefile`.  If `make` can't find `Makefile`, try `make -f path/to/Makefile`.  Why are you bothering with an old version of glibc anyway?  [The current stable version is 2.13](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/#CurrentStatus)

Comment: @Ben Voight , Thank you for your answer. When we try your suggestion make -f path/to/Makefile --included-dir=path/to Makefile , we get back the error MakeConfig:85: sysdeps/../config,make :No such file or directory .make: Failed to remake makefile sysdeps/../config.make . But I thought the configure we ran was error free. Maybe it wasn't. Could you suggest a workaround? We will switch to 2.13 as you suggested but all we need is the syscall-list.h file which you mentioned. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Ben Vight, Thank you for all of your help. I finally got the make running on glibc-2.9. I followed your suggestions and I ran configure --prefix=path/to/Makefile followed by make and everything started running OK. We got a syscall-list-h file. For mmap , all it says is: #define SYS_mmap __NR_mmap. Thank you,

Comment: @Frank: You could run `grep` or `ctags` on the directory to find the definition of the `mmap` function.  Possibly it will be the same code  @onteria already included in his answer (that says auto-generated).  Either way, the part in glibc is not interesting, it just sets up a syscall.

Comment: @Ben Voight, Thank you for your suggestion. If it turns the mmap function is the same assenbly code which @onteria included in his answer, what is the purpose of the kernel mmap.c code? We are wonndering what the relationship is between glibc mmap and the kernel mmap.c code. Does @onteria's assembly code interface with the kernal mmap.c code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Frank: It won't be the same assembly code, because each processor family has its own assembly language.  But do you see the `int $0x80` line in @onteria's code snippet?  That a software interrupt, which invokes the kernel.  All glibc does is put the system call arguments in the registers expected by the kernel, and call to the kernel.  That's why the glibc part isn't very interesting, because all the real work is done in the kernel.  The kernel syscall handler ends up calling the code in `mmap.c` (after it checks the syscall number and sees that it's an mmap2 request).

Comment: @Ben Voight, Thank you for answer. I just accepted your answers. I believe the kernel syscall handler has code which looks like this #define __NR_mmap xx _syscalln(long,xyz,void* start , size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset) . would you happen to if know where in the Centos Linux 5.5 distribution (for example /usr/xxx/xxx...) I can find the kernel syscall handler for mmap? I wouldn't expect you to have a Centos Linux 5.5 distribution handy.So, where could I find this information? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My immediate guess would be that trying to figure out how to use these better from the source code to the functions is likely to be (at best) a very roundabout way to get much of anywhere. In particular, you're probably going to have to look at quite a lot more/other code to get much of anywhere. When you get down to it, the code in mmap/MapViewOfFile itself is likely to be of minimal help (at best) and other code (such as in the file-system driver and file cache) is likely to be a lot more meaningful.

When you get down to it, mmap and MapViewOfFile have relatively simple jobs: set up page descriptors that map a range of virtual addresses to some part(s) of some file.

Not much else/more happens until you attempt to access one of those pages. That'll trigger a "not present" fault. The fault handler will use the I/O subsystem to read in the corresponding data from the disk, and the return to let the original instruction execute. Still not much that's very interesting.

At least from the viewpoint of optimization, the point that things get interesting is inside the I/O subsystem. That may (for example) keep track of the history of page faults, and use that to predict what pages are likely to be needed soon (and if so, issue reads for the predicted pages before the fault happens).

At best, however, the source code to mmap/MapViewOfFile isn't going to lead at all directly to the parts of the I/O subsystem you probably care about (in fact, they'll probably be almost entirely useless in this respect).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess what you are saying is that the most interesting part of mmap is in the I/O subsytem code. Thank you for your help. I'll start acccepting answers this evening.

Comment: @Frank: Yes, but the I/O subsystem code that's involved isn't part of mmap at all. mmap just sets up page descriptors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess what you are saying that it is impossible to read the I/O subsytem code used by the kernel mmap.c. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: No, I'm saying that mmap.c won't use the relavant code directly at all. The fault handler for the "page not present" fault will. The code is there and can be read (at least in Linux), but there won't be anything leading directly from mmap.c to the part you care about (it won't directly call anything interesting).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I appreciate your clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, but I needed mmap source, too... :)

So far I could find the answer only on NetBSD.
[Based on this comment](http://www.unix.com/302859197-post4.html):

- The libc function is in [src/lib/libc/sys/mmap.c](ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-release-8/src/lib/libc/sys/mmap.c)
- The corresponding kernel function is in [src/sys/uvm/uvm_map.c](ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-release-8/src/sys/uvm/uvm_map.c):

  int uvm_map(struct vm_map *map, vaddr_t *startp /* IN/OUT */, vsize_t size,
  struct uvm_object *uobj, voff_t uoffset, vsize_t align, uvm_flag_t flags)

The actual links correspond to NetBSD release 8, but you can replace it with any other release.

Regards.